# "Load balancing" a powerbank to power small wireless camera

Tags: batteries, solar-energy, camera

I'm doing a very small project to power an off-grid wireless camera. I have a 20 Ah powerbank that supports pass-through and I hooked it to a small 5 W solar panel (which looking [at this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188455/noobie-is-trying-to-match-a-solar-power-bank-and-a-wireless-camera) might be too little). The camera is a [USB powered Eufy outdoor cam](https://us.eufy.com/products/t8442121) and the power supply is rated as 5 V/1 A, which is the same as one of the powerbank USB outputs.

What I would like to do is have a "backup" powerbank which gets used in case the main battery doesn't have enough juice. I thought maybe a small microcontroller could help with that, however at the cost of consuming more power. Any ideas or pointers in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered getting a 40 Ah powerbank?

Comment: I did, but there aren't that many which support pass through so it gets a bit expensive..